# fetch form values in while loop and insert into MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am trying to insert form values into MySQL table, but the form is in while loop, so basically i want to add multiple values, i am using foreach but due to some problem only first two values are being inserted into the table and rest of the values are either missing or in correct, i am attaching the code as well as the result screenshot.

```
<?php
$i = 1;
$counter = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($questions)) {
    ?>
    <div class="control-group">

        <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">(<?php echo $counter; ?>)
            <?php
            $questionid = $row['question_id'];
            $question = $row['question'];
            ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="questionid[]" value="<?php echo $questionid; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="question[]" value="<?php echo $question; ?>" />
            <?php echo $row['question']; ?></label>
            <div class="controls">
            <?php
            if ($row['answer_type'] == "Ratings") {
                echo "
                                                                                                                        <p>

                                                            Low<input type='radio' name='rating$i' value='1' id='rating_0'>                                                                                                         
                                                            <input type='radio' name='rating$i' value='2' id='rating_1'>                                                         
                                                            <input type='radio' name='rating$i' value='3' id='rating_2'>                                                          
                                                            <input type='radio' name='rating$i' value='4' id='rating_3'>                                                      
                                                            <input type='radio' name='rating$i' value='5' id='rating_4'>High                                                   

                                                        </p>
                                                                                                                        ";
                $i++;
            } else if ($row['answer_type'] == "Comments") {
                echo "<textarea name='answer[]' cols='' rows=''></textarea>";
            }
            echo "<br />";
            $counter++;
            ?>

        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Action File Code

```
foreach($_POST['questionid'] as $key=>$questionid){

    $questionid = $_POST['questionid'][$key];
    $answer = $_POST['answer'][$key];

    $ratingKey = "rating".$key;
    $rating = $_POST[$ratingKey];

    $result3 = mysqli_query($con, "select question,answer_type from questions where question_id=$questionid;"); 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) {
        $question = $row['question'];
        $answer_type = $row['answer_type'];

        if($answer_type == "Comments") {
        $query2 = "insert into review_details (review_id,survey_id,question_id,question,answer_freeresponse) values(1,$_SESSION[surveyid],$questionid,'$question','$answer')";          
        $result2 = mysqli_query($con,$query2);                                                          
        if(!$result2) {
        echo mysqli_error($result2);
            }
        }
        else if($answer_type == "Ratings") {
        $query2 = "insert into review_details (review_id,survey_id,question_id,question,answer_rating) values(1,$_SESSION[surveyid],$questionid,'$question',$rating)";         
        $result2 = mysqli_query($con,$query2);                                                          
        if(!$result2) {
        echo mysqli_error($result2);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Form Submitted

[image]

Result Screen Shot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `$counter` in all the brackets of the names in your code like: `"answer[]"` becomes: `"answer['.$counter.']"`.

`"questionid[]"` is written in another way, so it beocmes: `"questionid[<?php echo $counter;?>]"`, etc...

That would solve your current issues with iterating arrays, but I would advice to inspect and rewrite **all** of your code. All of your sql queries are wide open to injection...

Comment: @RajeshVishnani - just spotted it might happen and updated the answer.

Comment: hi, shouldn't be my text area's name 'answer$counter' instead "answer['.$counter.']", because i get correct answers for all except this.

Comment: `'answer$counter'` is an option, too. You should change the server side code to read from `$_POST['answer'.$key]`.

Comment: no :( i tried that, do not get the correct value for the answers whose answer type is comments.

Comment: If it works for `$rating` it should work for `$answer`, too. Double check your fresh code for typos.

Comment: i have used if and else if, so lets say my if condition is executed and counter is incremented, at that time, else if's counter will not incremented, if i am not wrong? that might be the problem, what say? b ut i tired keeping another counter for the comments, it still doesn't work. please see if you can help, i am stuck at this point since long.

Comment: YES! Finally, its working, thanks a tons for the help. :) had to keep another counter for comments and at the server side kept the same code as ratings to retrieve the data.